# I can't install "python-gtk2" on kali 20.04

Tags: python, gtk2, kali-linux

I need to install "**python-gtk2**" on **kali 20.04** which is running on **virtual box**.

I used `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2` and the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gtk2
```

Here is the full details:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-get install python-gtk2                                                                                    100 ⨯
[sudo] password for kali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gtk2
```

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file content:

```
# See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# Additional line for source packages
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

**There is Debian Package** of python-gtk2 available. You can try to install it from there. 
Link: https://pkgs.org/download/python-gtk2

- apt install **command will not work** as gtk2 removed from Kali distro repository.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was removed from the Kali distro on 09/23/2020.
https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/pygtk

See also
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?45985-Can-t-seem-to-find-zenmap-other-tools&highlight=zenmap

I don't think there's much that can be done in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential`
3. `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`
4. `chmod 777 --Your debian file name--`
5. `dpkg -i --Your debian file name--`
6. `zenmap`
7. Installation complete.

Hope it helps your question :))

Comment: Not really, please explain how this works and why it helps.